# how to store session data in file in expressjs?

Tags: node.js, session, express

When user login, i am storing data in session like this :

```
   req.session.user = userData;
```

And it is working fine but when i restart in nodejs, the session is null. Then user need to login again.

I want to create a file based storage for session.But after a lot of search, i got the way to store data in database but i dont want to store session data in database. I want to store data in file.

Is there a nodejs module to store the session data in file?

Comment: File system is not the best place to store session data. Consider using some fast key-value storage (e.g. [Redis](https://github.com/tj/connect-redis)), or at least a database (e.g. [MongoDB](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)).

Answer (score 11):

You can use `session-file-store`. can refer below working example.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');
var FileStore = require('session-file-store')(session);

app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    store: new FileStore,
    cookie: { maxAge: 3600000,secure: false, httpOnly: true }
  })
);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>');
    res.end();
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1;
    res.end('Welcome to the file session demo. Refresh page!');
  }
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try [connect-fs2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-fs2).

```
var FSStore = require('connect-fs2')(express);
var options = { dir='./mySessionFolder' }; // specify your directory to store your session files

app.configure(function() {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({
    store: new FSStore(options), // use it as your store
    secret: 'your secret',
    cookie: { maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 } // 1 week
  }));
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: There may be problems with this on more recent versions of express, as middleware has been unbundled & this is very old package. I'm currently trying https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store

Answer (score 0):

Butt isn't it something like whenever we logedin  session data is store in file and we at the moment we logout session data which are store in file they may get delete...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
You forgot to install:
$ npm install session-file-store
source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-file-store

Answer (score -4):

its not a good idea to write session data in file , because you need to stores as key , value pair and have to parse it. if the user logout you need to delete particular session from file (otherwise the file may goes out of memory)

you say , you have stored session data in db , you need to add additional status information as key value pair in db. that status should only become false when the user terminates the seesion or session timeouts , otherwise it remains true even if server restart.with reference with this status you can hold the users.

Comment: This is not an answer

Comment: there are usecases for it: e.g.: In dev I don't want to spin up a DB but want to keep the session when the server reloads.